# How to deploy 2 apps to Heroku from one gruntfile?

Tags: heroku, gruntjs

I want to deploy 2 web apps in

```
/build/app1 

/build/app2
```

folders from the gruntfile in the root.

```
grunt deploy:app1
grunt deploy:app2
```

will be the commands.

Script should connect to heroku, and run  'git add' and 'git push heroku master' commands.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you paste the Gruntfile code you have already?

Comment: I just copy and preprocess files now.